# Sending JSON Object with newline

Tags: android, json, newline

I have a JSON object (email body), I need to append some strings from my activity then send post the data. The string should be formatted like this:

Name: (data from edit text)
Contact: (data from edit text)
Department: (data from edit text)
Message: (data from edit text).

I have no problem with formatting the string. Now the problem is when i am posting that data it is displayed as a single line. Is there any way to send a formatted string without losing the newlines?

```
finalMessage = finalName + System.getProperty("line.separator") + finalContact +
                            " \r\n"+ finalDept + " \n"
                     + "\n \n \n" + "Dear Doctor Dondi," + "\n\n \t\t"
                     + finalMessageBody;
```

Comment: Why do you want the newline?

Comment: @FireSun Not just one newline, he wants all the formatting preserved.

Comment: Did you try doing double escaping (\\r\\n \\n, etc.)? Maybe that will help.

Comment: Yes i have tried \\n. "\n" appeared when i retrieved the data.

Comment: "Now the problem is when i am posting that data it is displayed as a single line" , Where are you displaying the sent data?

Comment: Solved it by changing \n to <br>. Thanks for all the response.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing \n to `<br>`. Apparently the email can read html codes.